# ffmpeg, Audiostream: How to get type (fourcc) of it with the API?

Tags: api, audio, ffmpeg

This seems to be a too simple question,
but I was not successful in getting it:

I have no problems with decoding a stream and accessing the data.
But I also need the bitrate and the type of the stream.

The bitrate and the codec used I get by AVCodecContext's members
bit_rate and codec_id.

But I don't need the codec used but the stream type
(as the codec AV_CODEC_ID_MP3 is used for mp1, mp2 and mp3 for example).

I tried AVStream.id, but it is always 0.

Looks like I'm mixing up things, but where?

Answer (score 0):

`AVStream->codecpar->codec_type` will have the media type (video, audio, subtitles..) and `AVStream->codecpar->codec_tag` will have the codec string read from the input **if** the input records that data. A MP3 file won't, an AVI will.

Comment: Thanks (Yes, you're right, mp3 leaves codec_tag at 0). Actually in general I don't know the type of the audio (could be anything). At this point I do need to know. But how do get that information? It must be possible, as "MediaInfo"-app provides it for any format.